# MySQL Replication - Percona Toolkit Table Sync - Foreign Key Constraint Fails

Tags: mysql, database-replication, percona

I am trying to keep my development database up-to-date with data from my production database. I discovered [`pt-table-sync`](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-table-sync.html) in the [Percona Toolkit](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/index.html).

When I run it, I frequently get the error `Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`. This happens on tables that are frequently updated and have foreign keys.

Is there a way to make use of this tool that avoids this problem? Some other tool I'm missing? The database is quite large. The largest table has nearly eight million rows.

Comment: Do you really NEED realtime updates? The error you're seeing is probably because a child row is inserted before the parent row exists. The order of the updates is important when using FK constraints. Check and see if Percona Toolkit allows you to specify the order tables are replicated.

Comment: @SloanThrasher - This isn't real-time. I'm planning to run it every hour or so. I know it can be run for individual tables or for an entire schema. I'll check into table order.

Comment: Why aren't you using [MySQL Replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html)? That would ensure the data is inserted in your replica database in the same order as it was inserted on the master. You could either leave replication going all the time, or else turn it on and off periodically to "catch up".

Comment: @BillKarwin - I will look into that. I was under the impression that like `pt-table-sync` would be better than for an environment that was more ephemeral than I pictured a "slave" database to be. I will need to understand the implications of making changes to my development instance in this scenario as well.

Comment: Good point -- replication won't correct the data if you make local changes to data during development. See my answer for more suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried the --no-foreign-key-checks switch?

Comment: @PaulCampbell - Thanks for suggesting that. I tried it, and it fixed the problem.

Comment: @Sonny Well, I'd only ever used pt-table-sync for sorting replication issues but it seems like quite a simple way for resetting individual tables for Dev and QA data so we both got something out of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can temporarily disable foreign key checks on your local dev database:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

Then run pt-table-sync to change data so it's back in sync with your production database.

Don't forget to reactivate the FK checks:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Edit: Paul Campbell rightly points out in the comments above that pt-table-sync has a [--no-foreign-key-checks](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-table-sync.html#id6) option. This disables FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS in the session for the pt-table-sync connection.

But honestly, I wouldn't use pt-table-sync. Here's what I would do:

Take a full backup of my production database and download the whole backup to my dev local platform. Use [Percona XtraBackup](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-xtrabackup) to acquire a physical backup of production.

Then I can reinitialize the dev database repeatedly using the backup:

1. Shut down MySQL Server
2. Copy the backup files over the MySQL datadir
3. Start MySQL Server

You may reinitialize your dev database this way many times for each backup you copy from production. You could acquire a new backup once a day.

As a side benefit, you'd be in the habit of backing up your database regularly (which you should do anyway).

Whereas using pt-table-sync would require reading data from your production database every time you reinitialize your dev database.

I don't consider tables of 8 million rows to be very large.

Comment: When I said "large" I was meaning to communicate that my manual process was time-consuming. I was creating a database dump, clearing out my development box, and loading the dump file. The eight million rows represents about eight months of data.

Comment: If you try the Percona XtraBackup solution, you should find that backing up is faster than mysqldump, and restoring is *very* fast. You just use `rm` to remove the old datadir and then `cp` to copy your backup into a new datadir. There's no dump file. The backup is exactly the files that can be used as a new datadir. You don't need to load anything.

Comment: The backup took just under a minute. Now it's time to automate!

Comment: My database name is `reporting`. I copied the contents of that directory from the backup to my development server. When I try to `SELECT *`, I get a "ERROR 1812 (HY000): Tablespace is missing for table..." error.

Comment: I started reading up on restoring a single schema and decided that the nuclear option was the way to go. It would be great if they made that process simpler in the future.

Comment: You're referring to the transportable tablespaces? Yeah, doing a multi-step process for each table is tedious. It cries out for some community-developed tool to automate it.